# Wordpress: subpage's content seems hidden

Tags: css, wordpress

i'm working on this website http://josedelavega.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/

The homepages is pretty fine, but when i add content into others subpages this does not works. Looks like hidden. Ther's something wrong into the code? I just modified the template (http://themeforest.net/item/orquidea-responsive-wordpress-theme/5120180) adding this CSS rules:

```
.logo { float: right; margin-top: -8px !important; margin-right: 70px; }

nav#topmenu ul li { font-size: 15px; }

nav#mobilenav .logo { float: left; margin-right: 0px !important;  }

.sectionboxtitle { display: none !important; }

.bodyfont { display: none !important; }

.descrtext { padding-top: 10px; }

.skinselector { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This hides subpage content:

```
.sectionboxtitle {
    display: none !important;
}
```

If you just want it to be hidden on the start page I'd recommend something like this:

```
.home .sectionboxtitle{ display: none;}
```